# How to close slideshow when you're at the end of the index?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using Nextjs/Sanity. Have a slideshow with an index of images, I want it to close when you click the 'next' icon when its at the last image in the gallery. So far I'm able to close the gallery if you click the previous arrow on the first image like so:

```
const slidePrev = () => {
      slideIndex === 0
      ? setSlideIndex( imagesData.length - 1)
      : setSlideIndex( slideIndex - 1)
      if(slideIndex <= 0){
        setOpenImage(false)
      }
  }
```

But its still registering an (undefined) image when I try to apply the same rule to the next arrow for the final image:

```
 const slideNext = () => {
      slideIndex + 1 === imagesData.length
      ? setSlideIndex(0)
      : setSlideIndex(slideIndex + 1)
      if(slideIndex + 1 >= imagesData.length + 1){
        setOpenImage(false)
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`slideIndex` is an index value of an array that start at index `0`. `imagesData.length` is the amount of item in the array. So if your last `slideIndex` is `4`, it means that there is actually `5` items in the list.

That said the condition in `slideNext` shouldn't be `slideIndex + 1 >= imagesData.length + 1` but `slideIndex + 1 >= imagesData.length`.

Comment: That hasn't worked either unfortunately. I've tried numerous variations of that bit, and I just keep getting `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image')` as the error, I assume because its trying to read the next image when there isn't one

Comment: @paparonnie please try to fix that before.

Comment: That's what I'm doing here. I'm pretty sure this is what's causing the error message to pop up. When going next on the final image, it tries to read the next image in the list but there is no image to read, so its coming back as undefined. Thus, I want to close the slideshow when you click next on the final image. I had the same error when clicking the previous button on the first image as it was trying to read an image before index[0], so I did what I have above- have the slideshow close when you click previous. All my images work otherwise.